# Load listener on store of Extjs 4 not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4, listener, store

I was looking for something like 'load' listener of store in Extjs 4, but I am facing some problems.

1) I was under impression that 'success' parameter to 'load' listener method tells us whether operation was successful or not, but 'success' parameter contains one array. I dont know what do that array contains but after invoking 'success.length' property I found out that it contains actual number of rows which my server side code had sent as a response. So I think 'success' property actually contains my data, but I am not sure about it.

2) If I use Ext.each() method on 'records' or 'success' parameter, I am not able to see actual data loaded. How to see the actual data?

Code for store looks as below :

```
Ext.define('myCompany.store.customerDistribution', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/customerDistribution/customerCount.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'array',
            root: 'resultset'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records, success) {
            /*console.log('store - ' + store +
                        ', typeof(store) - ' + typeof(store) +
                        ', records - ' + records +
                        ', records data - ' + records.data +
                        ', success - ' + success +
                        ', type of success - ' + typeof(success)+
                        ', success length - ' + success.length);
            if(records == true) {
                console.log('records is data property...');
            }
            if(store == true) {
                console.log('store is a data property...');
            }
            for(r in records) {
                console.log(r + '\ttypeof(r) -> ' + typeof(r));
            } */
            if(success && records.length > 0) {
                var allCountries = [];
                var previousCountry = undefined;

                var countryIndex = 0;
                var stateIndex = 1;
                var cityIndex = 2;
                var customerCountIndex = 3;

                Ext.each(records, function(record, index){
                    console.log('record - ' + record[0] + ', ' + record[1]);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to convert row based json to hierarchical json to be displayed in tree panel. That is why I am using load listner.
My Json looks as follows :

```
{
    "queryInfo":{"totalRows":"100"},

    "resultset":[
        ["India","India","India",63],
        ["India",""," Tirupati ",1],
        ["India",""," UTTARPARA ",1],
        ["India","Andhra Pradesh",null,61],
        ["India","Andhra Pradesh"," Chittoor ",1],
        ["India","Andhra Pradesh"," Guntur ",2],
        ["India","Andhra Pradesh"," Hyderabad ",58]
      ],
    "metadata":[
        {"colIndex":0,"colType":"String","colName":"Country"},
        {"colIndex":1,"colType":"String","colName":"State"},
        {"colIndex":2,"colType":"String","colName":"City"},
        {"colIndex":3,"colType":"Integer","colName":"customer_count"}
    ]
}
```

and I want to convert it to :

```
"resultset": [
    countries: [
    {
        name: "India",
        customer_count: 63
        states: [
            {
                name: "Andhra Pradesh",
                customer_count: 61,
                cities: [
                    {
                        name: "Tirupati",
                        customer_count: 1
                    },
                    {
                        name: "UTTARPARA",
                        customer_count: 1
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Chittoor",
                        customer_count: 1
                    },

                    {
                        name: "Guntur",
                        customer_count: 2
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Hydrabad",
                        customer_count: 58
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have choosen wrong load event signature. In `TreeStore` it has following signature `load( Ext.data.TreeStore this, Ext.data.NodeInterface node, Ext.data.Model[] records, Boolean successful, Object eOpts )`. In addition records are arranged in tree structure, so you can't iterate through them with `each`.

Here is example code which logs each record in tree to console:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Task',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'treegrid.json'
    },

    logRecord: function(r, depth) {
        if (!depth) { depth = ''; }
        console.log(depth + Ext.encode(r.data));

        Ext.each(r.childNodes, function(record, index){
            this.logRecord(record, depth + '    ');
        }, this);
    },

    listeners: {
        load: function(sender, node, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function(record, index){
                this.logRecord(record);
            }, this);
        }
    }
});
```